# In-app billing library in android enterprise

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-enterprise

I have some troubles about using ***in-app billing library v3*** in managed devices using ***android enterprise***

In my public app I have two sku objects (subscription items) to be purchased, those objects should load as alert dialog when the app starts, but currently any sku object doesn't load, checking logs I found this message: `Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3`

Doing a research about this issue, I found that probably it could be that there is not account signed up on google play store, it make some sense, because **android enterprise** generates and signed up an bot account in every device registered, ex: *android12312@android23131.com*

Another possible solution is update de google play store app, but I'm not sure if I can do it, I suppose that android enterprise does it automatically.

Also, I tested public app in my personal device (it is not using android enterprise) and it loads sku objects correctly and this is reinforcing google's account theory.

Have you ever faced this issue before? I want to know how you solve it or any contribution is welcome. Thanks